# Will Google Chrome update itself considering that it has been downloaded as a standalone .deb file?

Tags: installation, package-management

I guess my question applies to software in general. Sometimes software is only available through .deb files, or sometimes up-to-date software is only available through downloaded .deb files, so will I lose automatic updating capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Google Chrome

The .deb file of Google Chrome adds a repository automatically to your software sources - you will get automatic updates once a new version appears in the stable channel.

With it in your software sources, you can also easily swap between the stable, beta and unstable versions of Google Chrome: `google-chrome-beta` and `google-chrome-unstable` can be installed simply from Synaptic or the terminal way (installing either one will first ask to remove `google-chrome-stable`).

Go to **Software Sources** > **Other Software**, in the list you will see:

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
```

Comment: As for software in general, another popular application that does this is Steam, which (if downloaded from steampowered.com) adds its own repository. Concerns are justified in most other cases, I think, but as soon as Ubuntu's repository has a _newer_ version of that application, that newer version will be installed.